# Stack Exchange API not realtime?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, api, rate-limit, realtime

I was testing the `inbox/unread` API but noticed that there is a **big delay** between one gets a message, and this message gets included in the API response. Like one minute or more.

Is this API not real-time, and is there a way to get real-time unread inbox items?

It would be essential for me, as I'm making an app to give user live notifications about new inbox messages.

Comment: By definition a real-time system has "real-time constraint"— e.g. operational deadlines from event to system response. So, if the response is guaranteed to be with in a minute I believe it would still be called real-time.

Comment: Oh thanks for the explanation on real-time! So I think my constraint would be like 20 or 30 seconds.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Every response from the API can be cached for up to a minute, so making the same request multiple times in that time-frame typically won't return different results.

We make note of this in the [throttle documentation](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/throttle):

> While not strictly a throttle, the Stack Exchange employs heavy
>   caching and as such no application should make semantically identical
>   requests more than once a minute.

Comment: So it's not possible to notify the user immediately with the API :(